# Script redirect command output to last filename argument

Tags: linux, bash, shell

File name:Tree(executable)

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $*
do
    if [ -d $i ]; then

        echo "===================$i================" >> ????? 
        tree -L 1 $i >> ?????
    fi
done
```

---

As you see, I want to list the tree structure of the parameters that I input,I want to let all the tree structure redirect to the last file(it's id is $#),it is "?????" in this script,because I do not know how to write it.

For example:

```
./Tree ./* README
```

YES,all directory tree structure will write in README!

Comment: You could just write to stdout and let the user redirect wherever they want: `./Tree ./* > README`. That way they could view the output on screen or pipe it to `less` or what have you.

Answer (score 3):

It would be easier/simpler to do this if your output file was the *first* argument instead of the last.

That would just need

```
output=$1
shift
```

added to the top of the script.

Using the last argument isn't harder really it just involves more "advanced" variable usage:

```
#!/bin/bash
output="${@: -1}"

for i in "${@:0:${#@}}"
do
    if [ -d "$i" ]; then

        echo "===================$i================" >> "$output"
        tree -L 1 "$i" >> "$output"
    fi
done
```

Where `"${@: -1}"` is the last element in the array of arguments and `"${@:0:${#@}}"` is the arguments from `0` to `${#@}` (the length of `$@` which is the count of arguments to the script).

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to put the name of the output file *first*, so that it doesn't interfere with the variable-length list of files you iterate over:

```
#!/bin/bash
output=$1
shift

for i in "$@"; 
do
    if [ -d "$i" ]; then

        echo "===================$i================" 
        tree -L 1 "$i"
    fi
done > "$output"
```

Then call your script as

```
./Tree README ./*
```

Better yet, there's really no need to pass the name of the output file to the script; just let the script write to standard output and do the redirection outside.

```
./Tree ./* > README
```

Comment: You should probably advise using `"$@"` and `"$i"`.

Comment: If I just only want to put the output file in the last ,What should I do?